# Integrate original elasticsearch-php library into Laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, elasticsearch

I am first day to Laravel and i need to intgerate original elasticsearch-php library.
https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-php

I've downloaded it via composer but don't know how to make it work the right way with Laravel.

Basically i want to use it that way:

$client = new ElasticSearch\Client();

Please help.

Comment: Used that package : https://github.com/shift31/laravel-elasticsearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following lines to your `composer.json`

`"shift31/laravel-elasticsearch": "1.0.*@dev"`
`"elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~1.0"`

Follow the rest of the install instructions at https://github.com/shift31/laravel-elasticsearch#usage

For good measure, i am providing some starter boilerplate code for you to save your data using that library.

FYI, I use my environment to differentiate between indexes (production or testbed). You may use other methods, such as a config.php value.

**Create mapping**

```
$params = array();
$params['index'] = \App::environment();
//params' type and array body's 2nd element should be of the same name.
$params['type'] = 'car';
$params['body']['car'] = ['properties' => 
                            [
                            'id' => [
                                'type'  => 'long'
                            ],
                            'name' => [
                                'type'  =>  'string'
                            ],
                            'engine' => [
                                'type' => 'string'
                            ]
                        ];

$client = new Elasticsearch\Client();
$client->indices()->putMapping($params);
```

**Insert document**

```
$params = array();
$params['index'] = \App::environment();
$params['type'] = 'car';
$car = \CarModel::find($data['id']);
if(count($car))
{
    $params['id'] = $car->id;
    //Elasticsearch doesn't accept Carbon's default string value. Use the below function to convert it in an acceptable format.
    $params['timestamp'] = $car->updated_at->toIso8601String();
    // toArray will give you the attributes of the model AND its relations. This is the bothersome part where you will get more data than what you need.
    $params['body']['car'] = $car->toArray();
    \Es::index($params);
}
```

**Update Document**

```
$params = array();
$params['index'] = \App::environment();
$params['type'] = 'car';
$car = \CarModel::find($data['id']);
if(count($car))
{
    $params['id'] = $car->id;
    $params['body']['doc']['car'] = $car->toArray();
    \Es::update($params);
}
```

**Delete Document**

```
$params = array();
$params['index'] = \App::environment();
$params['type'] = 'car';
$params['id'] = 1;
$deleteResult = $client->delete($params);
```

Comment: Laravel 5 now provides you with [laravel scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scout), with simple integration to elasticsearch